# How to display selected menu item in ul dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu that displays font colors for user choice. At the moment, the dropdown displays 'style', however I would like the menu title to display the currently selected value. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="font_dropdown" class="dropdown">
    <nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
    <ul>
      <li class="current-menu-item"><a>
      <li><a href="#">Style</a>
        <ul class="font-names">
          <li style="font-family: Raleway"><a>Raleway</a></li>
          <li style="font-family: palatino"><a>Palatino</a></li>
          <li style="font-family: impact"><a>Impact</a></li>
          <li style="font-family: courier"><a>Courier</a></li>
          <li style="font-family: Copperplate"><a>Copperplate</a></li>
          <li style="font-family: Monospace"><a>Monospace</a></li>
          <li style="font-family: Fantasy"><a>Fantasy</a></li>
          <li style="font-family: Calibri"><a>Calibri</a></li>
          <li style="font-family: Cursive"><a>Cursive</a></li>
          <li style="font-family: Futura"><a>Futura</a></li>
          <li style="font-family: Rockwell"><a>Rockwell</a></li>
          <li style="font-family: Andale Mono"><a>Andale</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#primary_nav_wrap
{
  margin-top:15px;
  font-family:raleway;


}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-family:raleway;

}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:32px;
  padding:0 15px;
  z-index:100;



}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0;
  z-index:100;

}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
  background:#ddd;
  color: orange;
  z-index:100;

}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
  background:#F3F4F5;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: orange;
  z-index:100;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  background:#fff;
  padding:0;
  z-index:100;

}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
  float:none;
  z-index:100;
  width:235px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
  line-height:120%;
  padding:10px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  left: 100px;
  z-index:100;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
  top:0;
  z-index:100;
  left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
  display:list-item;
  color: orange;
  z-index:100;
```

Javascript:

```
  $(document).on("click", '.font-names li a',  function() {    
      $("#imagewrap h3").css("font-family", $(this).parent().css("font-family"));
      $("#new_tile_font_style").val($(this).parent().css("font-family"));
   });
```

Sorry for messy code, I'm relatively new to this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a bit of code that uses jQuery to do it:

```
$(".font-names > li").click(function() {
   $("#menutitle").text($(this).text()); 
});
```

You'll also need to add an `id` to your menu title element.

**Live Demo:**

```js
$(".font-names > li").click(function() {
   $("#menutitle").text($(this).text()); 
});
```

```css
#primary_nav_wrap
{
  margin-top:15px;
  font-family:raleway;


}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-family:raleway;

}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:32px;
  padding:0 15px;
  z-index:100;



}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0;
  z-index:100;

}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
  background:#ddd;
  color: orange;
  z-index:100;

}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
  background:#F3F4F5;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: orange;
  z-index:100;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  background:#fff;
  padding:0;
  z-index:100;

}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
  float:none;
  z-index:100;
  width:235px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
  line-height:120%;
  padding:10px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  left: 100px;
  z-index:100;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
  top:0;
  z-index:100;
  left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
  display:list-item;
  color: orange;
  z-index:100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="font_dropdown" class="dropdown">
    <nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
    <ul>
      <li class="current-menu-item"><a>
      <li><a id="menutitle" href="#">Style</a>
        <ul class="font-names">
          <li style="font-family: Raleway"><a>Raleway</a></li>
          <li style="font-family: palatino"><a>Palatino</a></li>
          <li style="font-family: impact"><a>Impact</a></li>
          <li style="font-family: courier"><a>Courier</a></li>
          <li style="font-family: Copperplate"><a>Copperplate</a></li>
          <li style="font-family: Monospace"><a>Monospace</a></li>
          <li style="font-family: Fantasy"><a>Fantasy</a></li>
          <li style="font-family: Calibri"><a>Calibri</a></li>
          <li style="font-family: Cursive"><a>Cursive</a></li>
          <li style="font-family: Futura"><a>Futura</a></li>
          <li style="font-family: Rockwell"><a>Rockwell</a></li>
          <li style="font-family: Andale Mono"><a>Andale</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

JSFiddle version: https://jsfiddle.net/m129zd8m/

Comment: This works perfectly in the JSFiddle, however when I copy it exactly, it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: @ScottMyers Are you properly including jQuery? If not, insert this tag into your document's `<head>` tag, before all of your other script tags: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Oddly enough I did include jQuery correctly. Still isn't changing, So weird.

Comment: @ScottMyers You also remembered to add the id to your menu title element, correct?

Comment: When I select 'No wrap <head> tag' instead of 'onLoad' in the jsfiddle jQuery options, the same error occurs. What does this mean?

Comment: @ScottMyers That probably means you need to put the script tag with my jQuery code at the end of your `<body>`, rather than in your `<head>`.

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much for your help, once again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you add the class `current-menu-item` to the ul you want to select?

Answer (score 0):

Bind a click event handler to your `li` items and replace the text for the `li`.

```
$('.font-names li').on('click', function () {
    var $currentMenuItem = $('.current-menu-item a'),
        currentText = $('a', this).text();

    $currentMenuItem.text(currentText);
});
```

But looks like your `HTML` is a bit malformed

```
 <ul>
      <li class="current-menu-item"><a>   <----
      <li><a href="#">Style</a>           <----
        <ul class="font-names">
```

The right selector has to be changed based on it.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/cobr4j8w/)**