# create MENU [ CSS or javascript ]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

## how can make this idea>>gif/example > to any code?

#### this is a dropMenu, when click first time > open > and click any sub-menu item > close the menu and change the word for that item selected, 
online example: [ http://huber.com.ve/menu-equilatero/muestra1.gif ]

[this is the idea for >DropMenu > it is just an "image/.Gif"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0dyP.gif)

Comment: possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31795622/how-to-display-selected-menu-item-in-ul-dropdown-menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31795622/how-to-display-selected-menu-item-in-ul-dropdown-menu)

Comment: how change > $("#menutitle").text($(this).text());  to an image // not text

Comment: this helped , thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="List Name">Select List name</label>
<select name="list" id="list" class="form-control">
<option >Select</option> 
<option value=abc>abc</option>
<option value=xyz>xyz</option>
</select>
```

This is jsp code.Try this i think this can help you

Answer (score 0):

**exmple(80%) online > http://huber.com.ve/1.html**

```
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>

  <li><a id="menutitle"  href="#">&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;</a>
    <ul class="font-names">
      <li style="font-family: Raleway"><a style="text-decoration:none" href="http://huber.com.ve/hablemosBTN.jpg" target="_blank">rerererer</a></li>
      <li style="font-family: palatino"><a>Palatino</a></li>
      <li style="font-family: impact"><a>Impact</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```