# How to implement drop down menu into this code?

Tags: html

How would i got about implenting a drop down menu into this code?
I did try something before but i had trouble alinging the bar items after i implemented a drop down menu.

Cheers

```
<div id="menubar">
    <ul id="menu">


   <li><a href="example1.html">Example1</a></li>
       <li><a href="example2.html">Example2</a></li>
       <li class="selected"><a href="example3.html">example 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="example.html">Example 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="example.html">Example 5</a></li>
         <li><a href="example.html">Example6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Style.css

```
  #menubar
{ width: 898px;
  height: 52px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;} 

ul#menu, ul#menu li
{ float: left;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;}

ul#menu li
{ list-style: none;}

ul#menu li a
{ letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font: normal 100% arial, sans-serif;
  display: block; 
  float: left; 
  height: 17px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  padding: 9px 26px 6px 26px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: transparent;} 

ul#menu li a:hover, ul#menu li.selected a, ul#menu li.selected a:hover
{ color: #FFF;
  background: transparent url(transparent_light.png) repeat;}
```

Comment: The standard way to make a drop down is with <select> and <option> tags. What do you mean by having trouble aligning the bar items?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953482/how-to-make-a-pure-css-based-dropdown-menu or maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31795622/how-to-display-selected-menu-item-in-ul-dropdown-menu